# Emgucv How to convert FileNode to Matrix?

Tags: c#, c++, emgucv

```
<CM1 type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    5.1385274254160595e+002 0. 3.2910027190134770e+002 0.
    5.1238136591053387e+002 2.5289438862525913e+002 0. 0. 1.</data></CM1>
```

I have an xml file that contains a matrix.

In c++, we can use this:

```
FileStorage fs("camera parameters.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat CM1;
fs["CM1"] >> CM1;
```

to get the matrix object.

How can I do this in C#?

```
FileStorage fs = new FileStorage("camera parameters.xml", FileStorage.Mode.Read);
Mat CM1;
CM1 = new Mat(fs["CM1"]); //doesn't work, stuck here
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a `Mat` object from an xml file using a `FileStorage` object, you can use the `FileNode.ReadMat()` method.

```
Mat CM1 = new Mat();    
FileStorage fs = new FileStorage("camera parameters.xml", FileStorage.Mode.Read);
if (fs.IsOpened)
{
   fs.GetNode("CM1").ReadMat(CM1);
}
```

Make sure you instantiate the Mat object by calling `new Mat()` first to avoid a memory access violation exception.